# Referring to headlines in different localizations of Word?

Tags: localization, ms-word

I have a word document that I need to exchange with users in a different culture of Office. I am in daDK, other user in deDE.

When we exchange document, the field code in header

```
{STYLEREF "Overskrift 1" \* MERGEFORMAT}
```

fails on other side because in deDE Headline 1 is named differently. It would of course be the same the other way.

Is there any way to overcome this ? Can I use a different way to refer to a headline (enum?) or can I somehow programmatically from VBA avoid the issue ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a really bad example of over-localization. And apparently you cannot even use the internal names ("heading1" etc.) in the fields. 
AFAIK, you have the following options to get around this:

- Avoid the built-in styles in your docs.
- Create the header programmatically using the WdBuiltinStyle enumeration, i.e. something like this:

  ```
  ActiveDocument.Styles(wdStyleHeading1).NameLocal
  ```
- Surprisingly, this seems to work as well for the different heading levels (but I don't know why and whether there are side effects).

  ```
  {STYLEREF "1" \* MERGEFORMAT}
  {STYLEREF "2" \* MERGEFORMAT}
  ```